# What does each setting on the oven mean and what should you use it for?

Tags: equipment, oven, roasting

[image]

What do they mean, what is the best usage for each setting, and why?

Comment: Did you check the manual?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it has nothing to do with food and an answer can easily be found in a manual

Answer (score 2):

Depending on which manufacturer they may have differences in operation.  It would be best to check that manufacturer's website for a explanation, or the instruction manual.

[example 3 page guide](http://www.dreamkitchensuk.com/oven_symbols.html)

You should find a wealth of information by searching "Oven Settings Explained"